# .xstartup for KDE

Tags: kde, vnc

I'm trying diffeent .xstartup files to have KDE up when using thightvncserve, but I keep on seeing the empty screen. Any help?

current .xstartup is:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
vncconfig -iconic &
dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session &
startkde &
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
vncconfig -iconic &
dbus-launch --exit-with-session startkde &
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but with xfce. Below is the configuration that I've used to solved the issue adapted to KDE. Deleted all the configurations in `~/.vnc/xstartup` and add the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
startkde &


[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
```